# Is there a way to execute code dynamically in MySQL, similar to "execute immediate" in Oracle?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, execute-immediate

Like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in Oracle, is there any way to execute code dynamically in a MySQL stored procedure?

I really want to use a prepared statement within a MySQL stored procedure, to generate a new SQL statement in each iteration of a loop.

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB is supporting EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ince 10.2 KB doc is : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/

Answer (score 1):

It actually doesn't work like what I wrote.
I just code like:

```
set @preparedstmt = concat('SELECT tid, LENGTH(message) len FROM ? where tid=? and first=1');
prepare stmt from prepared_stmt;
execute stmt using v_tid;
drop prepare stmt;
```

Just take care of the table name,it shouldn't be replaced with the placeholder.So the @preparedstmt should be generated with concat method to make a statement,which is just replaced the parameters in conditions with placeholder,but not the table name.

Comment: Table name 'FROM ?' and other identifiers cannot be defined in the USING clause.