# Stored Function with group_concat in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-concat, stored-functions

I want create a Stored Function in MySQL. This Function have to include a group_concat function.

Here is my current SQL Query:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION SprachenListe(
paramTable VARCHAR( 50 )
) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC BEGIN 
DECLARE Ausgabe TEXT;
SET @tableName = paramTable;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ', @tableName.Sprache, ' ORDER
BY ',@tableName.Sprache,' SEPARATOR  ','/',' ) INTO ',Ausgabe,' FROM ',@tableName);
RETURN(Ausgabe);
END ;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is Error Message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT ', @tableName.Sprache, ' ORDER BY ',@table' at line 6

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: You probably came from Oracle. There is no execute immediate in MySQL. This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567277/is-there-any-corespondent-in-mysql-like-execute-immediate-in-oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use dynamic SQL, which in MySQL is done using prepared statements, with `PREPARE` followed by `EXECUTE`.... however, in MySQL, these are only supported in stored procedures, not stored functions.

> SQL syntax for prepared statements can be used within stored procedures, but not in stored functions or triggers.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html</sup>